# MEF dependency questions

Tags: mef

Simple example.

Application A has a class library C which is used through out.

Application A uses MEF to discover and load plug in modules P1 and P2 from a plug in directory. One assembly per plug in.

P1 and P2 both have a dependency on C (The class library).

The build process will ensure the version of C used by P1 is identical to the version referenced by A.

**I assume that I won't end up with multiple copies of the same assembly loaded at once?** By default I end up with a copy of C in the Plugin directory as well as A's application directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure you don't end up with duplicate assemblies, you could change the `Copy Local` property to false of the contract (C) library in your plugin projects, that way on build, it won't be copied to the output directory.

You should be fine I think, as the CLR won't load the same assembly twice thanks to the Fusion loader rules - the first being to see if the target assembly is already loaded in the `AppDomain`. BUT, you have to be careful, because any code using `Assembly.LoadFrom` may result in exceptions occurring if it is actually finding that the assemblies have different locations on disk.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm going to have a bit of a play and make sure it doesn't do anything silly. I was a bit concerned MEF might override some of the assembly loading events and ... do things... :) Thanks.